# how to get rule Hierarchies along with 1-1 relationship with mongo projection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb document like below Where 2 collection `Demo` and `Rule` has 1-1 relationship, like `Demo1` has a linked `RuleId`,

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62165ded19477d42a62629e0"},"Name":"Demo1","RuleId":{"$oid":"62165c6242615a8f9341495b"}}
```

`Rule` collection has parent-child kind of relationship where `Rule1` has No parent

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62165c5c42615a8f93414959"},"Name":"Rule1","ParentRuleId":{"$oid":"000000000000000000000000"}}
```

`Rule2` parent  = `Rule1`

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62165c6142615a8f9341495a"},"Name":"Rule2","ParentRuleId":{"$oid":"62165c5c42615a8f93414959"}}
```

and `Rule3` parent  = `Rule2` and so on....(NOT FIXED)

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62165c6242615a8f9341495b"},"Name":"Rule3","ParentRuleId":{"$oid":"62165c6142615a8f9341495a"}}
```

Now I want to JOIN both collection `Demo` and `Rule` and need below data kind of data,

```
Name: Demo1
Rule Hierarchies: [Rule3, Rule2, Rule1]
```

Can this projection possible in C# with MongoDb driver, please suggest mongo language projection query also, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  You can use `"$graphLookup"`to recursively follow all the parents.  Strangely, `"$graphLookup"` doesn't guarantee to maintain order of the lookups, but `"depthField"` can be used to track it.  To put everything in order, `"$unwind"` the `rules` and sort on the `"depthField"`.  `"$group"` assembles your desired output.

```js
db.Demo.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Name": "Demo1" } },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "Rule",
      "startWith": "$RuleId",
      "connectFromField": "ParentRuleId",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "rules",
      "depthField": "recursiveDepth"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$rules" },
  { "$sort": { "rules.recursiveDepth": 1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "Name": { "$first": "$Name" },
      "Rule Hierarchies": { "$push": "$rules.Name" }
    }
  },
  { "$unset": "_id" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/im-DCPwxZPc).

Comment: An interesting contribution would be an aggregation pipeline that *does not* `"$unwind"`/`"$group"`, but instead somehow looks up the depths directly.

Comment: !  one question? Here I am using `link` as relationship. Is this good data model or some kind of link plus embedded  I can go? Please suggest!

Comment: @user584018 Your data model should match how you intend to use the database.  I would review [MongoDB Data Modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) and consider how my database would be used in light of any performance advantages/disadvantages.